# How to fix the infinite loading problem with a WordPress plugin (Minerva KB)?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

- WordPress version 6.2.2
- Current plugin: Minerva Support: Knowledge
  Base | FAQ | Glossary | Tickets (version 2.0.9)
- PHP version 8.1.18

I have the plugin Minerva KB on my WordPress project, among others. One of the options of this plugin is the settings page, which allows me to customize my knowledge base design. Minerva's other features, like creating a topic, making a tag, and others, are working correctly, but when I try to access the settings pages, it loads endlessly.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem?
I couldn't find a channel to talk with the Minerva developers, and didn't find any other topic like that on the internet.

Error caught by WordPress when I try to load the setting page:

## Error Details

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 1369 of the file .../public/wp-content/plugins/minervakb/lib/helpers/settings-builder.php. Error message: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

[image: Page loading endlessly]

Comment: "I couldn't find a channel to talk with the Minerva developers", there is an email address on their Facebook page (check their website to find the link), have you tried contacting them via email yet?

Comment: Actually yes, but I got no answer. I will try once again...